# Ionic native using ionic/angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm currently working on a project in ionic/angular 1. I'm using ionic native to wrap the cordova plugins.

I installed ionic native with bower, and added dependency to 'ionic.native' in my app's angular module. Now I can inject stuff like $cordovaFile into my controllers and use them. This works great.

My problem is using the MediaPlugin. I inject $cordovaMediaPlugin in my controller. Now the documentation ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/mediaplugin/ ) says do this:

`new MediaPlugin('path/to/file.mp3', onStatusUpdate);`

Obviously i cant do this in angular1.

I tried stuff like this:

var media = this.$cordovaMediaPlugin('PATH');
var media = new this.$cordovaMediaPlugin('patch');

nothing seems to work, getting undefined all the time.

How would I make this calls in angular/ionic 1? I really think the 'new' keyword is the issue here...

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ngCordova Media plugin.

Install ngCordova, and inject in your app module 'ngCordova'.

1. See de following [steps](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)
2. Install [plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/)
3. If you want create a service to provide a media resources [see](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/media.js) (Not required)

Comment: I do not want to use ngCordova. I'm actually migrating from ngCordova to ionic-native because ngCordova is no longer maintained and ionic-native supports a lot more plugins.

Comment: @iCediCe did you ever figure this out?